Use a 2d array of datasets with Chart.js
I've changed the subject of my data for clarity and privacy, but my actual problem is identical.
I have data in the format of CSVs organized by region, all of the following format:
canada.csv:



year
Corn output (tons)
Potato output (tons)
Carrot output (tons)




2001
4000
1234
23423


2002
4354
2345
4343


2003
4322
2233
5120


...
...
...
...



I have this with identical crops for us.csv, mexico.csv, etc.
My end goal is to have a chart.js line chart where different subsets of the countries and crops can be displayed simultaneously. i.e. you could check "potato" and "corn" + "canada" and "mexico" and see the corresponding 4 line charts.
To me, this makes the most sense as a 2D array of datasets:
new Object = {
    canada:{
        corn:data,
        potato:data,
        carrot:data
    },
    mexico:{
        ...
    },
    us:{
        ...
    }
}

However, chart.js seems to expect a 1D array of datasets. I'm planning to use the setDatasetVisibility(datasetIndex, visibility) function from the API to control the visibility of the charts, but since that function accepts only an index, I'll have to find a way to match each subset of crop/country pairs with an index, which seems very fiddly.
I've tried to construct a list of objects in the following format:
[{
    country:canada,
    crop:corn,
    index:0,
    hidden:true,
    data:{
        x:year,
        y:output
},
{...
}...]

For all combinations of country and crop, in hopes that this object will both help me find the index I need to control the visibility and that I can put this into the data field of chart.js to have it render each dataset. Implementing this has been extremely cumbersome and I keep running into issues with how I structure my data and led me to wonder if there was a better way.

Do you mean to have a chart with 9 lines representing all combinations of countries and crops? I can do it using "cartesian product" of the countries and crops. Indeed, the interface is dubious - maybe you should consider some colors - but it has all the series.


const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var csvs = {}
var crops = ["corn", "potato", "carrot"]
var countries = ["canada", "us", "mexico"]
var combinations = cartesianProduct([countries, crops]);
// console.log(combinations)

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234242/3807365
function cartesianProduct(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.map(function(x) {
      return b.map(function(y) {
        return x.concat([y]);
      })
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b)
    }, [])
  }, [
    []
  ])
}

// generating random data
countries.forEach(function(country) {
  csvs[country] = []
  for (var year = 2015; year <= 2024; year++) {
    var line = {}
    line.year = year
    crops.forEach(function(crop) {
      line[crop] = Math.random() * 12000
    })
    csvs[country].push(line)
  }
})

// datasets combinations
var datasets = []
var years
combinations.forEach(function(combination) {
  var country = combination[0]
  var crop = combination[1]
  var csv = csvs[country]
  years = csv.map(item => item.year)
  var data = csv.map(item => item[crop])
  var dataset = {
    label: country + ' - ' + crop,
    data: data,
    borderWidth: 1,
  }
  datasets.push(dataset)
})

// the chart
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: years,
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>




Thank you so much for your response! Yes, this result is similar to what I've been able to get. My problem is that I'd like to control the visibility of the lines based on category, and I can't figure out a good way to do that. I'm trying to a checkbox labeled "canada" that would show all canada crops if checked, and hide all if unchecked. And the same for all countries+all crops. That way you can compare all the crops of one country, or all the counties' output of one crop, or any combination of those.

How do you envision the UI for this? 6 checkboxes?

Thought I should come back to this. 6 checkboxes is the UI I ended up going with. To dynamically enable and disable categories, created a helper object which included the index of each data in the dataset, and filtered that to find which indexes to show/hide using chart.setDataVisibility().
